Сохранение только среднего дневного значения столбца в таблице clickhouse
У нас есть таблица в кликхаусе в которой мы храним большие объемы данных которые прибывают постоянно и так же в большом количестве.
Оригинальная таблица имеет несколько столбцов, самые важные для этого кейса это столбец типа float который и содержит значение среднее которого нам нужно, и столбец целочисленного типа содержащий таймстемп.
Мне необходимо создать отдельную таблицу в которой будут хранится средние значения float столбца за 1 день, и так каждый день. И еще некоторые другие столбцы.
Вопрос: какой движок MATERIALIZED VIEW лучше использовать для такой задачи.
Я пробовал создание таблиц таким образом:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily_metrics_data
(
    ...
    ...
    day                DATE,
    average_value      Float64
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree
      ORDER BY (day);


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS avg_per_day_mv TO daily_metrics_data
         AS SELECT toStartOfDay(any(timestamp)) AS day,
               avg(value(i need to compute avg of this orig value from orig table))    AS average_value,
               toStartOfDay(any(timestamp)) AS day                                                              
FROM ... GROUP BY ..., ..., ...

